# Change text of a specific row in uitableview?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

Is it some how possible to update text of a specific row in uitableview. like for example I have 3 rows A B C . and now I would like to add another row to the table like row with D I know you can do it with reloading the table but that would take a lot of time (there is alot of data to be put in). so is it possible without reloading the entire table.

thanks, 
Tushar Chutnai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this method of UITableView class:

```
- (void)insertRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation;
```

[source](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use either:

```
insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:
```

OR

```
insertSections:withRowAnimation:
```

depending on your type of table.

Read the Apple developer's documentation on UITableView class [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and check out the Instance Methods section in that. Should solve your troubles.